# Why struct size do not match with plain sum of item's sizes?

Tags: c++, c, padding, memory-alignment

With C/C++ structs, normally, the final struct's size is the plain sum of the sizes of all its elements, but there are cases which this is not true.

I am looking at the technical answer (it has to be one) of why the following struct's size is not equal to the size of all its members:

```
#include <iostream>

struct {
    int a;
    long b;
    char c;
} typedef MyStruct;

int main() {
    MyStruct sss;
    std::cout << "Size of int: " << sizeof(int) << std::endl << "Size of long: " << sizeof(long) << std::endl << "Size of char: " << sizeof(char) << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Size of MyStruct: " << sizeof(sss) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Thas has the following output:

```
Size of int: 4
Size of long: 8
Size of char: 1
Size of MyStruct: 24
```

So it can be seen than the size of `MyStruct` is not `4+8+1 (13)` rather, it is actually `24`, but why?

Comment: Alignment. There are more questions on this with good answers.

Comment: Look up the concept of struct padding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because C allows compilers to add padding between the elements of a `struct` to make the generated code more performant.

Some hardware allows accessing multi-byte data faster when such data is placed at memory addresses divisible by the size of the data. For example, accessing a 32-bit `int` may go significantly faster when the `int` is located at address `0x8004` or `0x8008` than when the same `int` is located at an address `0x8003` or `0x8006`. The standard allows compilers to adjust offsets of `struct` members to make use of such optimization.

Moreover, there are platforms where accessing a multi-byte value *not* aligned with the memory space results in an error: for example, reading a 16-bit `int` from an odd address in 68000 architecture triggers bus error. Compilers know this, and they add unused space to your `struct` so that accessing multi-byte fields does not trigger an error.

Comment: *Or* simply to conform with the underlying architecture (many processors don't accept unaligned memory accesses, depending on the size of the access).